# Setting UIImageView Width According To Screen Size

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am trying to set an image's width to 75% of the screen width and positioned in the middle.

1. I've tried to get the screen size
2. I've tried to assign the `size.width` to my image

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var logo: UIImageView!

    var sSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let sWidth = sSize.width
    var image = UIImage(named: "logo");
    image = sWidth * 0.75

    @IBAction func btnPlay(sender: AnyObject) {
        logo.hidden = true
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried autolayout?

Comment: Have you tried auto layout. You can set the width of the UIImageView to be 0.75 of the width of the container view. Then play around with the image scaling options.

Comment: The auto layout box is checked but I really don't have a clue how to sort this out.

Answer (score 1):

This following line shouldn't compile:

```
image = sWidth * 0.75
```

Since image is a UIImage and not a CGFloat! (sWidth is CGFloat)

Change your code as follow:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var logo: UIImageView!
}
```

And in the storyboard use autolayout:

> add a these constraints between the imageView and the viewController's view:
>
> 1. equal height
> 2. equal width with multiplier of 0.75

Also -> try using the storyboard more: add the image to the imageView through the storyboard.

if you don't want to do this, add it in code inside viewDidLoad.